# iphone modal view - how to go back to parent parent parent controller

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I have several views that I open one after another modally.  View1 calls View2 and View2 calls View3.
I use this code to call the next view:

```
   View2 *myView = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];   

    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];

    [myView release];
```

If the user pushes cancel then it goes back one View… 3 to 2 and 2 to 1

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What I need to do is when the user is on View3 if they don’t select cancel but complete the operation, then I need to go back to View1 and release View2 and View3.

How do I  do that?

**EDIT:  The MAIN WINDOW has a Navcontroller and 6 view controllers.  I call the View 1 like this**:

```
View1 *screen = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.Search = screen;

    [mainNavController presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

    [screen release];
```

**EDIT #2:
Main Windows calls View 1.  Main Window has a NavController in the XIB this works:**

```
    View1 *screen = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


[mainNavController presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

[screen release];
```

Then in the XIB on View 1 I added a NavController and tied it to View1NavController in the .h

View 1 then calls view 2:

```
   View2 *myView = [[[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController * navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView] autorelease]; 

[View1NavController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

When I execute this, no errors, but it doesnt show the View2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use `UINavigationController`? You can use both `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:` for your purpose.

As such if you do,

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You should go back to `1`.

Excerpt from [`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW30),

*If you present several modal view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of modal view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.*

**Using Navigation Controller**

For navigation controller to work, instead of where your load your `view1` you will do this,

```
View1 *myView = [[[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
UINavigationController * navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView] autorelease]

[mainNavController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

*This is assuming that `view1` was the `rootViewController`*

Once you've the navigation controller set up then you can load `view2` like this,

```
View2 *myView = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];   
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
[myView release];
```

In such case,

**Cancel**

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Complete**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: How do I call the view in the first place if I use the NavController?

Comment: Which view are you talking about?

Comment: If I am on View 1 and want to show View 2.  The code above is how I do that now.  If I use a NavController what does the code look like then?

Comment: Added a bit about doing it using navigation controller. Take a look and let me know if you've issues with something in the answer.

Comment: I am guessing I need to add a NavController to the XIB?  And then I need to attach "Window" to the .h?  On the line that says self.window.root.... It give an error saying Property 'window' not found on object...

Comment: that is where the problem started.  On the Main screen (lack of a better name, sorry I am new to the iPhone stuff) I have a NavController and 6 view controllers. I will add the code above that I use to load View 1 from the main screen.  Since your last message I added a Window to the View 1 and now I have the window showing and the view is hidden.  I guess I have to tell it to show the View and not the window?

Comment: Am I supposed to have a 2nd NavController setup on View 1 that calls the other views maybe?

Comment: Yes. Replace `View1 *screen = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.Search = screen;
    [mainNavController presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];` with `View1 *myView = [[[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
UINavigationController * navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView] autorelease];
[mainNavController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];`

Comment: IT WORKS!  Thank you sir!  You have saved me hours of frustration trying to guess how this works!  thank you!!!!

Comment: OK that worked as I said.  It looks like I really need to get back to View 2.  So Main calls View 1.  View 1 calls 2 etc. The poptoroot goes back to View 1.  But what would I need to make it go to View 2.  I guess I need to add a NavController on View 1?

Comment: Can you please look at the top again Edit #2... Not sure what I did wrong?

Comment: I have already included what you need to do with `view2` – `View2 *myView = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];   
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
[myView release];`

Comment: You don't have to create a new navigation controller the second time. Since you are already on the second navigation controller you just create the `View2` instance and push it onto `self.navigationController`.

Comment: OK I must have missed something I guess.  What you gave me works.  The actual code is I think its View 4 we are on and need to get back to View 2, not View 1. So when I call View 1 I did it as I did before.  Then on View 2 I added the code you gave me thinking that would shift everything down 1 level.  but it didnt work.

Comment: I got it again.  On the last line it was mainNavController presentModalView.... etc.  I changed that to self presentModal... and that works.

Comment: [`Here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/Wizard.zip)'s some sample code that you can look into. Pretty basic but implements what I have put in my answer.

Comment: One each of the views I had a NavBar with Cancel (Back) and the title etc.  Now I have added the new NavController it has its own bar at the top.  Is there a way to hide the NavController bar or should I redo everything to use the NavBar

Comment: I am now further understanding what you had me to, with adding the NavController in code rather than in the XIB.  That is where I was confused thinking that you needed to always have it declared in the XIB.   If I did do it that way however then I guess I could see what the bar looks like at design time?>

Comment: You can do `navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` where `navController` is your navigation controller.

Comment: would you recommend hiding the bar or replacing my navbar

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Can't judge from here. If you think you don't need a nav bar, remove it.

Comment: I guess hiding it is easier at this point otherwise I would have to put it in the XIB or learn how to programmatically setup the bar for the controller

Comment: what I have is the navbar on all of the views is already setup and the buttons work etc.  changing it to the navcontrollerbar I would have to redo everything and not really sure how to see it on the XIB anyway. So to do it right, should I figure this out or just hide it>

Comment: Glad to help. If you want to do the navigation bar right. I would say redo it. Each view controller has a `navigationItem` property. Although you can't reassign it, you will have to add to it programmatically. If you think that's too much effort, then you can use your existing set up and hide the navigation controller's navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no smart way, try this stupid one:

```
  UIViewController *vc = self;
  while(vc.parentViewController.modalViewController == vc){
    [[vc retain] autorelease];
    [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    vc = vc.parentViewController;
  }
```

Comment: Wouldnt this release the one you are showing and then  stop the code?